# Create tasks[] an array of task

Tags: java, arrays, class, extending-classes

My current problem is that I am assigned to created a program that should within the private fields assign tasks[] an array of task. Then within the constructor, that creates the task[] array, giving it the capacity of INITIAL_CAPAITY, and setting numTasks to zero.

I am new and confused on I can tackle this problem

I have tried declaring it within the constructor but there has been no luck.

Task.java

```
public class Task {
    private String name;
    private int priority;
    private int estMinsToComplete;

    public Task(String name, int priority, int estMinsToComplete) {
        this.name=name;
        this.priority=priority;
        this.estMinsToComplete = estMinsToComplete;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public int getEstMinsToComplete() {
        return estMinsToComplete;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setEstMinsToComplete(int newestMinsToComplete) {
        this.estMinsToComplete = newestMinsToComplete;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return name+","+priority+","+estMinsToComplete;
    }


    public void increasePriority(int amount) {
        if(amount>0) {
            this.priority+=amount;
        }
    }

    public void decreasePriority(int amount) {
        if (amount>priority) {
            this.priority=0;
        }
            else {
                this.priority-=amount;
            }
        }
    }
```

HoneyDoList.java

```
public class HoneyDoList extends Task{
    private String[] tasks;
//this issue to my knowledge is the line of code above this

    private int numTasks;
    private int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 5;

    public HoneyDoList(String tasks, int numTasks, int INITIAL_CAPACITY,int estMinsToComplete, String name,int priority) {
        super(name,priority,estMinsToComplete);
        numTasks = 0;
        tasks = new String[]{name,priority,estMinsToComplete};
//as well as here^^^^^^^^
    }
```

My expected result is to be able to print out the list through honeydo class. I need to manipulate the code a bit more after adding a few other methods.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. I assume you get some sort of compiler error, or what exactly is your problem?

Comment: It gives me a type mismatch error saying a String[] cannot be converted into another String or int

Comment: except name, other variables (priority and estMinsToComplete) are int and you are passing them to String array. It will certainly not compile. `new String[]{name,priority,estMinsToComplete};`

Comment: You should think about your design, HoneyDo is a Task contains an array of String in which you seems to put **A** task info (name, prio, time)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your constructor parameter *tasks* has the same name as that field of your class.

So you assign to the method parameter in your constructor, not to the field. And **luckily** those two different "tasks" entities have different types, otherwise you would not even notice that something is wrong.

Solution: use

```
this.tasks = new String...
```

within the body of the constructor!

And the real answer: you have to pay a lot attention to such subtle details. And by using *different* names for different things you avoid a whole class of issues!

Also note: it sounds a bit strange that a class named Task contains a list of tasks, which are then strings. The overall design is a bit weird...